# RegEx problem with IE7 when trying validate Email address

Tags: regex, internet-explorer-7

I am wondering an annoying problem with Email Validation using regex.
I'm using this regex to validate email address on a web page:

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]{1,63})*@(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]{0,255}\.?\s*$)[a- zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}){0,126}\.([a-zA-Z]{2,63})\.?\s*$
```

Now this works allright with IE8 --> and latest Mozilla and Opera version for example.
I already read about this article: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug

But even I was using .* with ?= I could not get it working. Any RegEx guru have ideas what I'm doing wrong.
I also tried this:

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]{1,63})*@(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]{0,255}\.*?\s*$)[a- zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}){0,126}\.([a-zA-Z]{2,63})\.*?\s*$
```

But with no success.

Comment: What is the function of the lookahead? I don't see the usefullness in this case. Just copy paste a email regex from the internet like from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the space in the last group of

```
@(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-\.]{0,255}\.?\s*$)[a- zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}
```

right after the `-` intentional? This probably won't work with a conservative engine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this regex and it seems to do the job right:

```
const string myRegex = @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
        + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
        + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
        + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the lookahead altogether? I agree with @Gerben that it serves no purpose in your regex:

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_\+-]{1,63})*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}){0,126}\.([a-zA-Z]{2,63})\.?\s*$
```